# Переадресация с субдомена на директорию с сохранением параметров

Tags: .htaccess

Требуется сделать переадресацию с домена `test.site.com` на директорию другого домена `example.com/test` с сохранением всех параметров. 
Пример:
`test.site.com/news -> example.com/test/news`
`test.site.com/profile?show=edit -> example.com/test/profile?show=edit`

Как правильно настроить .htaccess для этого?

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.site.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/test/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```